# Dependency Injection with EF - is mapping required?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, entity-framework

I'm implementing the Repository pattern with using DI and EF6.

I created the database (that inherits from `DbContext`) object with the [Visual Studio wizard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/vstudio/cc716685%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) `ADO.NET Entity Data Model`

I have a generic `IRepository<T>` in my domain assembly, and its implementation in different assemblies based on the data source.

The problems come with the mapping objects from the EF to the domain objects: almost all of my code is writing things like

```
private Sql.Database.Cat Map(Domain.Data.Cat cat)
{
    return new Sql.Database.Cat
    {
        Species = cat.Species,
        Legs = cat.Legs,
        ...
    }
}
```

and the opposite of course. The mapping creates a big amount of problems, eg updating, but it is necessary in order not to add the `Sql.Database` dll as a dependency in the UI assembly.

Is there a way not to have to map objects and not having the EF assembly as a dependency as well?

Comment: How is the `Sql.Database.Cat` class written? By hand, or is it generated? (Are you using a Code-first or a Model/Database-first approach?) Are these classes POCOs?

Comment: I've used the Visual Studio wizard to auto-generate the classes from an existing database. Domain objects are POCOs, while Database ones are connected to the database via entity framework.

Comment: Which Visual Studio wizard did you use? Do the database classes inherit from a class in Entity Framework ?

Comment: I'm updating the question

Comment: What purpose is served by this sort of extreme decoupling?

Comment: Using a DI container with xml configuration I can switch the sql assembly with a mongodb assembly without recompiling or having to change anything

Comment: This kind of mapping is exactly what [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) is for